# Pandas - Usecols when columns exist in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Since the columns and list of usecols are different, it spits the error

"ValueError" Usecols do not match names.

How can I 'usecol' if columns exist in csv?

csv sample:

```
df.csv

AB,CD,EF,GH
foo,20160101,a,1
foo,20160102,a,3
foo,20160103,a,5
```

reading csv:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', 
    header=0,usecols=["AB", "CD", "IJ"])
```

This is what I'd like to get:

```
df

date       AB   CD
2016-01-01  a    1
2016-01-02  a    3
2016-01-03  a    5
```

Ignored "IJ".

Comment: Why do you have `"IJ"` int he `usecols` list?  Take it out.

Comment: It's just a sample, the df I'm using has hundreds of columns. At the time when I read_csv, columns in csv is blackboxed.

Comment: and you want the columns that are the intersection of `usecols` and what's in the csv?

Comment: yes, the intersection of "usecol" and columns in csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***import `csv` normally***

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """AB,CD,EF,GH
foo,20160101,a,1
foo,20160102,a,3
foo,20160103,a,5"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))

print(df)

    AB        CD EF  GH
0  foo  20160101  a   1
1  foo  20160102  a   3
2  foo  20160103  a   5
```

`reindex` with `intersection`

```
usecols = ['AB', 'CD', 'IJ']
df.reindex_axis(df.columns.intersection(usecols), 1)

    AB        CD
0  foo  20160101
1  foo  20160102
2  foo  20160103

​
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `lambda` in `usecols` to skip columns that not in `csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """AB,CD,EF,GH
foo,20160101,a,1
foo,20160102,a,3
foo,20160103,a,5"""

usecols = ['AB', 'CD', 'IJ']

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=lambda c: c in set(usecols))

print(df)

    AB        CD
0  foo  20160101
1  foo  20160102
2  foo  20160103
```

An explanation can be found in the pandas docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to **True**. An example of a valid callable argument would be **lambda x: x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']**. Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.