# reading columns of csv file using pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file

I am trying to read the following .csv file, but I want to read each column of it. However, usecols is not working as it is giving the following error:
`ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['sources', 'RMS']`

this is how I am reading it:

```
train=pd.read_csv("parameters.csv", usecols = ['sources','RMS'])
```

And this is my csv file:
[image]

how can I read each column of this file?
edit: I had an unclose " but the problem persists

Comment: The first few lines of the actual text content of the csv would be more beneficial than the image to see what's actually there to read.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) are you aware of the type (missing the closing quote in your csc_read statement) and 2) are you trying to read all columns or just the two selected with your usecols argument?

Comment: yes i fixed the closing quote and I am trying to read only those specific lines

Comment: As others have noted, there's probably a problem with the CSV file. Basically the error is saying it can't find a column named that in the file so I'd double check the file you are reading does have it and matches exactly to the names in your code AND are in the first row of the header, nothing above the column name

Comment: there is only the file name written above the table, but not as a row or column or anything

Comment: Again we really need to see the contents of the csv file to be able to determine what the issue is.

Comment: What do you mean? the CSV file would be spaced [C1], [C2], [C3] then the columns you could sort by would be C1, C2, or C3. From the sounds of it you don't start you CSV file with header information so pandas has no way to know which column "sources" is

Comment: Again, are you looking to read specific columns, or every column. You updated the question saying "how can I read each column of this file?" if you want to read EVERY column you can just remove the usecols argument. If you are trying to read specific columns (like sources and RMS) you have to use either their index (0-your last column number-1) or the header name, which has to be in your file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Usecols when columns exist in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127080/pandas-usecols-when-columns-exist-in-csv)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read each column, just remove the usecols part like so: `train=pd.read_csv("parameters.csv")`. I'm guessing the reason it doesn't work is that your columns have spaces after the names, so the actual name of one of your columns is something like `sources`    .

It might be an error on your part, but you have unclosed quotation marks in your code snippet.

Comment: if i remove usecols then how will I read the columns?

Comment: It reads all the columns by default. usecols limits it to only the two. You can select specific columns after reading all the columns first.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the columns will always be the same, you can also use an integer-list with `usecols`

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',usecols=[0,4] #this selects just 0 and 4
```